# How to hydrate an object with values taken from struct in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there in C# any hydrating technique allowing to transfer values from one struct/object to another struct/object if they have similar fields or based on certain strategy. I came from Zend Framework 2 world, and it provides the feature "Hydrator" which allows do exactly what I said above. So, I am wondering whether Asp.Net or C# provides something similar.

To make it clear, I want something like this:

```
struct UserInfo {
    public string FirstName { get; set; };
    public string LastName { get; set; };
    public int Age { get; set; };
}

class UserUpdateModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; };
    public string LastName { get; set; };
    public int Age { get; set; };
}
```

...

```
//supposed UserUpdateModel model I is gotten from the action param

UserInfo info = new UserInfo();

Hydrator hydrator = new Hydrator(Hydrator.Properties);
hydrator.hydrate(info, model);
```

Now, "info" should be populated with values from "model"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want something like [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) (as one example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). It is designed specifically for this. I personally prefer writing ViewModel constructor that takes an entity and copies the properties. I like the control and familiarity of good old C# code even if it takes a bit more effort.

Answer (score 2):

[Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) should do the trick. You can use it as a nuget package.

Once you have your types and a reference to AutoMapper, you can create a map for the two types.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserUpdateModel, UserInfo>();
```

The type on the left is the source type, and the type on the right is the destination type. To perform a mapping, use the Map method.

```
UserInfo info = Mapper.Map<UserInfo>(userUpdateModel);
```